# If $f$ is increasing, then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $P_n$ : $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \leq (b-a)/n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I've already proven that, if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and increasing, with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, then

$$U(f,P) - L(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[ f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})\right](x_i - x_{i-1})$$

Now I need to prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a partition $P_n$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \leq (b-a)/n$. There was a hint given, suggesting we try a partition where $x_i - x_{i-1}$ is the same for all $i$.

For whatever reason, on my first attempt, I forgot the result I had just proven and started with induction; I couldn't get past the base case. Then, I remembered what I had just done and started over; I still couldn't very far, and I was stymied by the same problem. So —

Using the above result,

$$
\begin{align}
\ U(f,P) - L(f,P) &= \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[ f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})\right] \\
\ &= \frac{b-a}{n}\left[f(b) - f(a) \right] \\
\end{align}
$$

If this is to be less than or equal to $(b-a)/n$, we cannot have $f(b) - f(a)$ greater than $1$; I see no reason why this must hold in general. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing says that $P_n$ must have $n$ points.

Comment: @Did: Thought about this on the ride home from work. First of two responses: I think I see where you're heading. Let $D = \lfloor f(b) - f(a) \rfloor + 1$. Define $P_n = \{ a + i((b-a)/Dn) : 0 \leq i \leq Dn \}$. Then everything seems to work out.

Comment: @Did: Second response: As someone who almost went for a linguistics degree before he went for a math degree, there's something kinda annoying about that :). (See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle).) Granted, I have a constant times $n$, but it's not $n$. I assume, in general, it's impossible to do with $1\cdot n$?

Comment: Indirect proof: if the error (b-a)/n was achievable for every function f with n points, it would be achievable for the function (c.f) and the error for (c.f) is c times the error for f hence the error (b-a)/(c.n) would be achievable with n points. For every c...